# Laravel 5.2 multi auth logout not working

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have implemented laravel 5.2 multi authentication.I have two guard `web(default)` and `admin(created new)`. I have logged out user using `Auth::logout()` but I am not able to logout admin.
I tried to logout with `Auth::guard('admin')->logout()` and `Auth::guard('admin')->user()->logout()`. But its not working.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code for logout method:
*App/Http/Controllers/LoginRegisterCtrl.php*

```
public function logout()
{
  Auth::guard('web')->logout();
  Auth::guard('admin')->logout();
}
```

Above code should work for you.